# Don't want to display two headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am a newbie to React-native and have been trying to develop an app through learning. Today, I read the official doc of React Navigation.
I referred and wrote some code but for some reason, two headers were being displayed on the screen. I read through the code I had again and again, but I couldn't find where it was wrong. I put the code below. There are some Japanese comments, but please don't mind them.

Thanks for taking your time and dedicating to this problem^^

```js
// Home.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  RefreshControl,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import xml2js from "react-native-xml2js";

export const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [rssList, setRssList] = useState();

  const fetchRss = async () => {
    await fetch("https://tech-parrot.com/feed/")
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((xml) => {
        const parser = xml2js.Parser();
        parser.parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
          setRssList(result.rss.channel[0].item);
        });
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRss();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
        data={rssList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Details", { item: item });
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title[0]}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.link}>
                  {new Date(Date.parse(item.pubDate[0])).toLocaleDateString(
                    "ja"
                  )}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </ListItem>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.link[0]}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  base: {
    padding: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
  header: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "500",
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
  },
  title: {
    color: "#000",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  link: {
    color: "#db7093",
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  separator: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
  },
});
```

```js
// App.js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"; // 新規追加
import { HomeScreen } from "./screens/Home";
import { DetailsScreen } from "./screens/Details";
import { ReadLaterScreen } from "./screens/ReadLater"; // 新規追加
import { MemoScreen } from "./screens/Memo"; // 新規追加
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons"; // 新規追加

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  // タブ移動の設定を新規追加
  // createBottomTabNavigator ... タブ移動を設定する関数
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  // 新規追加
  // - 移動を関数に持たせて、タブ移動の設定で利用
  // - 意図 ... タブ移動の箇所のコードが読みにくくなるため
  const Home = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="ホーム" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="詳細" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };

  // 新規追加
  // - 移動を関数に持たせて、タブ移動の設定で利用
  // - 意図 ... タブ移動の箇所のコードが読みにくくなるため
  const ReadLater = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="あとで読む" component={ReadLaterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="詳細" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };

  // 新規追加
  // - 移動を関数に持たせて、タブ移動の設定で利用
  // - 意図 ... タブ移動の箇所のコードが読みにくくなるため
  const Memo = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="メモ" component={MemoScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="詳細" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };

  return (
    // タブ移動の設定を新規追加 ====================
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;
            // ホームアイコンの設定を行っている ==========
            if (route.name === "ホーム") {
              iconName = focused // 『三項演算子』で条件分岐。選択中 or 未選択の場合のアイコンを変えることができる（今回は変えてません）
                ? "ios-home"
                : "ios-home";
            } else if (route.name === "Settings") {
              iconName = focused ? "ios-list-box" : "ios-list";
            }
            // 下記は、ホームと同様 ====================
            if (route.name === "あとで読む") {
              iconName = focused ? "ios-pricetag" : "ios-pricetag";
            } else if (route.name === "Settings") {
              iconName = focused ? "ios-list-box" : "ios-list";
            }
            if (route.name === "メモ") {
              iconName = focused ? "md-document" : "md-document";
            }
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "tomato",
          inactiveTintColor: "gray",
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="ホーム" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="あとで読む" component={ReadLater} />
        <Tab.Screen name="メモ" component={Memo} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // container: {
  //   flex: 1,
  //   backgroundColor: "#fff",
  //   alignItems: "center",
  //   justifyContent: "center",
  // },
});
```

Comment: Can you post some screen shot for this issue?

Comment: Please post screenshots of the issue you're having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigators have a default header. Since you are nesting them, you are seeing multiple headers. You can hide them by adding

```
headerShown: false
```

in the options prop of the screen or the screenOptions prop of the navigator.